# User Groups not working in one server. same is working in another server

Tags: lotus-notes, acl, lotus-domino

I am facing some interesting problem with groups in domino server.

I have created testACL group in names.nsf in TestServer1 server. Same address book replicated to TestServer2 server as names.nsf.  so typically both server share same address book.

When I add this testACL group in application A in testserver1 server, it is working and getting effect immediately.
But  same ACL group is added in application B in testserver2 , it is not working.

Please help me to find the solution. Please let me know if my problem is not clear.

Comment: You need to specify exactly what you mean by "not working".  What is the specific test that you are doing, step by step.

Comment: Hi Richard : Since individual ACL entries exceeded the limit, I am creating group and adding to the Application. When the User requesting for access, I add his name in the group in the address book(application and names.nsf - same server only). But still user is not able to open the applicaiton. It throws , You are not authorized. <br> But same scenario works in other server.

Comment: My Server name looks like Test01/OU/IN and Test02/OU/IN. I did updall after and before adding user in the group. But It is also not effective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution for this problem temporarily. I have deleted **cache.ndk** in Data Directory.

It is getting effective immediately. But Looking for permanent solution.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Have you tried to execute the command "show nlcache reset" on the console of the server you replicate to?